# Disjoint unions without tags

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have this situation and no means to meaningful change the data structure. So I cannot add a tag.
Is there a way to distinguish the types without a tag? I tried ducktyping, but it does not work. See my [example](https://flowtype.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeKARA9gO2gB8oBRAJzJzIG4oB6OqAQygBMBLeAKx3bzUR52+KKEhQA7u2AALURJxQAxk3gIAUGOi4CGKAG9lOQcABcUPIgC2AIwhkoAX03ho5Sg8yGrCeEwDmEObwwGR8-k7q6kr4IWw4AMo4PrLhAOrSMjrQmAAUODZc5tkAlBgAfAZ0AFQAdPXVdM4xeHGsickQqXj+GbLuVHr5heYDZGXolfo19bWNzlCLUNGxaABmQ2QIKGaw26gTU+qL7Bu5W0iotTEmZfrHS+1JKTLpmdnn+8AlD45QEMg1AYHosnp1ur1MmNPpdvr91I4gA)

```
type Result = Done | Error; // a disjoint union type with two cases
type Done = { count: number }
type Error = { message: string }

const doSomethingWithDone = (obj: Done) => {/*...*/}
const doSomethingWithError = (obj: Error) => {/*...*/}

const f = (result: Result) => {
  if (result.count) {
    doSomethingWithDone(result)
  } else {
    doSomethingWithError(result)
  }
}
```

The errors are:

```
 5: const doSomethingWithDone = (obj: Done) => {/*...*/}
                                      ^ property `count`. Property not found in
 10:     doSomethingWithDone(result)
                             ^ object type 
 6: const doSomethingWithError = (obj: Error) => {/*...*/}
                                       ^ property `message`. Property not found in
 12:     doSomethingWithError(result)
                              ^ object type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It does make sense, since your typings don't say that a `Done` cannot have a count property.
>
> Using exact objects types seems to partially work, in the sense that it does refine properly, as you can see in this [example](https://flowtype.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeKARA9gO2gB8oBRAJzJzIG4oB6OqAQygBMBLeAKx3bzUR52+KKEhQA7u2AALURJxQAxk3gIAUGOi4CGKAG9CSnIOAAuKHkQBbAEYQyhAL6bw0cpTJ7D1hPCYA5hAW8MBkfAHO6urGeKFsOADKOL6yEQDq0jI60JgAFDi2XBY5AJQYAHwGdABUAHQNNXQusfGsSSkQaXgBmbIeVHoFRRYDZOXoVfq1DXVNLlCLUDH48QBmQ2QIKOaw26gTU+qL7Bt5W0iodcam5frHS+3JqTIZWTnn+8ClD05QEMg1FBTlBPpdgHVfPB-EE7g9Fk9Ot1elkxmCdj9Fi4nEA). Sadly, you also have to do an explicit check in the else.

[By AugustinLF](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3390#issuecomment-280789445)

Comment: This approach will fail if the `count` is `0` or if `message` is `''`.  I am guessing that my answer was downvoted because, at first glance, my types look like they change the structure of your data, which you stated you cannot do. However, adding the optional fields is still compatible with the data you described, and this form permits you to check for `!== undefined`, which will take care of the falsey cases.

Answer (score 1):

Flow does not support this sort of thing as elegantly as it does disjoint unions. However, exact types can help. The problem in your example is that I could do

```
const x: Error = {message: 'foo', count: 'bar'};
f(x);
```

The assignment is valid because my object literal satisfies the `x` interface. So, while you know that if something is an `Error`, it has a `message` property, you do not know anything about what other properties it has. So, checking that the `count` property exists does not prove that you have a valid object of type `Done`.

Exact types can help here:

```
type Result = Done | Error; // a disjoint union type with two cases
type Done = {| count: number |}
type Error = {| message: string |}

const doSomethingWithDone = (obj: Done) => {/*...*/}
const doSomethingWithError = (obj: Error) => {/*...*/}

const f = (result: Result) => {
  if (result.count) {
    doSomethingWithDone(result)
  } else if (result.message) {
    doSomethingWithError(result)
  }
}

// Expected error. Since Error is an exact type, the count property is not allowed
const x: Error = {message: 'foo', count: 'bar'};
f(x);
```

([tryflow link](https://flowtype.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeKARA9gO2gB8oBRAJzJzIG4oB6OqAQygBMBLeAKx3bzUR52+KKEhQA7u2AALURJxQAxk3gIAUGOi4CGKAG9iSnIOAAuKHkQBbAEYQyUQgF9N4aOUqPMhqNYTwTADmEBbwwGR8QU6u6sZ44Ww4AMo4-rJRAOrSMjrQmAAUOLZcFnkAlBgAfAZ0AFQAdE11dK7xiawpaRAZeEHZsp5UekUlFkNkleg1+vVNDS2uUMtQcfiJAGYjZAgo5rC7qFMz6svsWwU7SKgNxqaV+qcrnanpMlk5eZeHwOVPzlAIMg1FBzlBvtdgA1-PBAiEHk9li9ur1+jkJhC9n9lq5YgxSAAPSBKYAQViAihUBpQZJ8JQeSmOTjMPCAglMEmidwAGlEMmgd34UDAlEgZFAoPglhwaCYyGQOAkZLWCTQBPGjL0+hhcNCUAA5BscDh9bzBft9bYmGR9c5qOoNgUCeVqEA))

Note that in addition to making the types exact, I had to change your `else` to an `else if`. And obviously, using exact types has the downside that your object cannot have extraneous fields. But, I think it's the best option if you absolutely cannot add a discriminator field in order to use disjoint unions.